# How do I ensure that only my app is able to register and receive messages sent from FCM?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently setting up a Firebase Cloud Messaging project. When adding apps to this project some credentials are automatically generated by FCM, e.g. the Server key as well as Android and iOS client keys.

For Android, I can download and use the google-services.json file to setup the client, i.e. registering for an FCM token and receiving push messages. But **how do I restrict this so only my app can receive these messages?**

I thought it would be the (auto created) Android client API key, so to test I've put an incorrect package name and SHA fingerprint in restrictions for the key. No effect, can still receive messages.

I then tried removing the API key as well as oauth client info completely from the google-services.json file, to confirm that the device then would not be able to receive messages. No effect, can still receive messages. All client info seems to be completely ignored, except for the app id (and the general project info).

So, I am really wondering what prevents reverse engineering of an app to extract the app id and general project info, and then receiving push messages in an entirely different app? I don't understand why the Android client API key, etc. is included in the google-services.json file, or why they are even created, if it is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been in contact with Firebase Support over the past week to shed light on this. It seems there is an important difference between the now deprecated Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) and Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), and it is currently not well documented.

With GCM it was possible to use and restrict e.g. the Android client API key with a package name and a SHA fingerprint. This is no longer possible with FCM. The keys are auto created when you add apps to your project in the Firebase console, and included in the google-services.json file, and you can add the restrictions to these under Credentials in APIs & Services, but it will not have any effect.

Please also note that the SHA fingerprint you can add in the Firebase project is only for Firebase Invites or Firebase Dynamic Links.

Be careful and have this in mind when you decide what to use the messaging service for, or when you migrate from GCM to FCM.

There is a feature request for this at Firebase but they currently have no timeline. There also a request now for an update of their documentation regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2):

All the information in `google-services.json` is essentially configuration data that your app uses to find the Firebase services on Google's servers. You should not rely on knowing it, or lack of knowing it, as a security mechanism.

Instead you should send your messages in a way that ensures they are delivered only to the targeted recipients. A large part of this is [sending messages to specific FCM Instance ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message). Firebase's Instance ID tokens are unguessable. Initially this registration token is only known on the client-side device where it is generated, and that device determines who to share it with.

By ensuring your client-side code only shares the token with your own server-side code, which then use it to target FCM messages, you can create a completely safe delivery environment where you fully control who can receive each specific message.

On the other side of this are [FCM topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging), which are a simpler mechanism for delivering messages to groups of users. Since any client can subscribe to any topic that it knows the ID of, topics should be used for delivering messages that require less securely targeted delivery.

Comment: Thanks Frank. What about the auto created Android (and iOS) client API key(s), what are they used for? and why are they included in the file?